# Whats wrong with the given code

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am just learning some pointers stuff in C and I happened to learn that using the * one can dereference the pointer. So I wrote the following code to check for that.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *findChar(char *s, char c){
  while(*s!=c){
     s++;
  }
  return s;
}

int main(){
  char myChar='a';
  const char myString[]="Hello abhishek";
  char *location;
  location = findChar(myString,myChar);
  puts(location);
  char temp = *location;
  printf(temp);
}
```

I assume that temp should get the value pointed by the character pointer location, But this program is giving me a segmentation fault. Please clearify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If your string doesn't have an `a` in it, your findchar routine goes out of bounds.  Also, consider using a debugger to find faults like the one mentioned by aix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is incorrect:

```
 char temp = *location;
 printf(temp);
```

If you want to print out the char, use the following:

```
 char temp = *location;
 printf("%c\n", temp);
```

The first argument to `printf()` should be the format string.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of printf should be `char*` (for the format), not `char`.

Try `printf("%c\n",temp);`

By the way, to see the index of `myChar` in the array, you may want to print `location-myString`

Answer (score 0):

The printf causes the segmentation fault, as printf expects a char pointer for temp and you pass a single char to it.